# Deleting the rows checked in a kendo grid

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid with file name and checkbox as columns. Each row has a file name and checkbox. I want to delete the rows, which are checked on click of a button.

I used the following code inside the onclick function.

```
$.each(grid.dataSource.view(), function () {
                var currentDataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                var dataRow = grid.dataSource.getByUid(currentDataItem.uid);
                grid.dataSource.remove(dataRow);

            });
```

But, i get a javascript exception like, uid is undefined. Please help me to get away from this.

Edit: Able to delete row by row. Not able to delete multiple rows in single shot.
Also, when i upload using kendo upload again after delete, all the files previously deleted are uploaded in single attempt.

Thanks 
Manikandan

Answer (score 2):

```
/Iterate through all the tr in grid
$.each(grid.find('tr'), function (item,index) {
           //check if the tr has a checked checkbox, you can be more specific here if you have multiple checkboxes in tr.
           if(item.children('input[type=checkbox].is(':chekced'))
           { 
            grid.dataSource.remove(item);
            }
        });
```

Few things which I want to share:

1. You cannot delete multiple rows at once without looping through grid data/view/rows
2. To remove any row, you need not to dig datasource and get dataItem, you can directly delete it based on the 'tr' (DOM elements)
3. If it says Uid is undefined, check the source of your rendered grid, it must has 'data-uid' attributed attached to each tr. If not, you have not specified the modal correctly.
4. After deleting if it still uploads the changes, you can call saveChanges method on grid datasource to freeze the changes you have made.

Answer (score 1):

Three questions:

If you iterate `grid.dataSource.view()` you will find only those elements that are in the current page of the grid. If you want to iterate through all elements of the table, you might use `grid.dataSource.data()` instead.

Iterating you don't need to `select` a row, since you already have the information in your function. Example, if you do:

```
$.each(grid.dataSource.view(), function(idx, elem) {
    console.log("item with index " + idx + " is ", elem);
})
```

then `elem` is the item on row `idx`.

Last but not least, when you iterate in an array starting from the beginning, you cannot remove elements since there are two consecutive elements that you want to remove, you will remove the first, then increment the counter for proceeding with the next **but** then the second is actually now in the position of the first so it will be skipped.

Example: If you have the following code:

```
var array = [3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4];
console.log("before", array);
$.each(array, function(idx, elem) {
    if (elem >= 5) {
        array.splice(idx, 1);
    }
});
console.log("after", array);
```

it will display:

```
before [3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4] 
after [3, 2, 1, 6, 4]
```

element with value `6` was not removed!!!

You should do, instead, start from the end:

```
var array = [3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4];
console.log("before", array);
var len = array.length;
while (len--) {
    if (array[len] >= 5) {
        array.splice(len, 1);
    }
}
console.log("after", array);
```

getting as result:

```
before [3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4] 
after [3, 2, 1, 4]
```

So, your code should be:

```
var array = grid.dataSource.data();
var len = array.length;
while (len--) {
    if (...) { // the condition for checking if the item has the checkbox ticked
        grid.dataSource.remove(array[len]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am able to figure out the condition to find the checked checkboxes. I tried if ($("#GridUploadstaffIDs1").find("input:checked")), but this becomes true for all the rows. How to proceed now?

Comment: I would need to see your code to see what is wrong **but** then you will have the problem on making sure that you remove the rows starting from the end. Why do not loop through the datasource elements? Since this is pure JavaScript and do not require jQuery, it is likely to be much faster!

Comment: This is the code part which deletes the checked rows. var grid = $('#GridUploadstaffIDs1').data("kendoGrid"); var array = grid.dataSource.data(); var len = array.length; while (len--) { if ($("#GridUploadstaffIDs1").find('input:checked')) { grid.dataSource.remove(array[len]); } }

Comment: sorry, is not the checked field part of your model? Why do you use jQuery for getting it instead using the variable behing the checked box?

Comment: Can you please explain me clearly on this, to find a solution?

Comment: Please provide you schema model. Update the OP for including it.